# jq in a Jenkins pipeline not saving output to variable

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jq

So in my Jenkins pipeline I run a couple of curl commands across different stages. I store the ouput of Stage1 into a file and for every item in that list I run another curl command and use the output of that to extract some values using jq.

However from the second stage I can't seem to store the jq extracted values into variables to echo them later. What am I doing wrong?

```
{Stage1}
.
.
.
{Stage2}
def lines = stageOneList.readLines()
lines.each { line -> println line
                        
stageTwoList = sh (script: "curl -u $apptoken" + " -X GET --url " + '"' + "$appurl" + "components/tree?component=" + line + '"', returnStdout: true)                                
pfName = sh (script: "jq -r '.component.name' <<< '${stageTwoList}' ")
pfKey = sh (script: "jq -r '.component.key' <<< '${stageTwoList}' ")
echo "Component Names and Keys\n | $pfName | $pfKey |"
}
```

returns in the end for Stage2

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ jq -r .component.name
digital-hot-wallet-gateway
[Pipeline] sh
+ jq -r .component.key
dhwg
[Pipeline] echo
Component Names and Keys
 | null | null |
```

Any help in the right direction appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed `true` as the argument for the `returnStdout` argument to the shell step method for `stageTwoList`, but then forgot to use the same argument for the JSON parsed returns to the next two variable assignments:

```
def lines = stageOneList.readLines()
lines.each { line -> println line
                    
  stageTwoList = sh(script: "curl -u $apptoken" + " -X GET --url " + '"' + "$appurl" + "components/tree?component=" + line + '"', returnStdout: true)                                
  pfName = sh(script: "jq -r '.component.name' <<< '${stageTwoList}' ", returnStdout: true)
  pfKey = sh(script: "jq -r '.component.key' <<< '${stageTwoList}' ", returnStdout: true)
  echo "Component Names and Keys\n | $pfName | $pfKey |"
}
```

Note you can also make this much easier on yourself by doing the JSON parsing natively in Groovy and with Jenkins Pipeline step methods:

```
String stageTwoList = sh(script: "curl -u $apptoken" + " -X GET --url " + '"' + "$appurl" + "components/tree?component=" + line + '"', returnStdout: true)
Map stageTwoListData = readJSON(text: stageTwoList)
pfName = stageTwoListData['component']['name']
pfKey = stageTwoListData['component']['key']
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. Will try out the JSON parsing natively in GROOVY too. Hadn't considered that.